# Django Session management with Vercel

Tags: python, django, vercel

I have a Django web app currently hosted on Vercel that displays a users top artists and tracks. It utilises the Spotify API to retrieve the access token and request the data. In my app the access token is saved using a class however I've come to a problem where if a user does not enter the site via the main page eg: spotify-app.vercel.app/ and goes straight to spotify-app.vercel.app/top-tracks they see the data of the last person who logged in because the token is saved in the class. I'm also assuming this site would not work when multiple users are on. How would I go about storing the access token for just the current user rather than saving it on the server.

I have tried using the sessions library however vercel does not support it. How else can i manage my user sessions?

class:

```
class SpotifyAPI(object):
    access_token = None
    access_token_expires = datetime.datetime.now()
    access_token_did_expire = True
    client_id = None
    client_secret = None
    scope = None
    redirect_uri=None
    token_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    
    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret,redirect_uri,scope, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret
        self.redirect_uri = redirect_uri
        self.scope = scope

    def is_token_expired(self):
        # Check if the access token has expired
        access_token = self.get_access_token()
        if not access_token:
            return True
        
    def login(self):
        
        authorization_url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' + urlencode({
            "response_type" : "code",
            "client_id" : self.client_id,
            "scope" : self.scope,
            'redirect_uri': self.redirect_uri
        })
        return authorization_url

   
    def auth(self,code):
        auth_options = {
            'url': 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            'data': {
                'code': code,
                'redirect_uri': self.redirect_uri,
                'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
            },
            'headers': {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(f"{self.client_id}:{self.client_secret}".encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
            }
        }

        response = requests.post(**auth_options)
        
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Parse the response content as JSON
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            response_data = response.json()
            access_token = response_data["access_token"]
            token_type = response_data["token_type"]
            scope = response_data["scope"]
            expires_in = response_data["expires_in"]
            refresh_token = response_data["refresh_token"]

            expires = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=expires_in)
            if expires <= now:
                access_token, refresh_token, expires = self.refresh_spotify_token(refresh_token)

            

            self.access_token = access_token
            self.access_token_expires = expires

        else:
            return redirect("fail")
```

URL routing:

```
def start_page_redirect(request):
    
    return redirect("spotify-auth")

def fail_view(request):
    return render(request, 'fail.html')


def spotify_auth(request):
    
    auth = spotify_api.login()
    return redirect(auth)


def spotify_callback(request):
    
    #get code and state form URL
    code = request.GET.get('code', None)
    state = request.GET.get('state', None)

    if code :
        spotify_api.auth(code=code)
        return redirect("top-tracks")
```

Comment: Do not initialize the variables at class level. Expect you want them to be shared over all instances.